# Python: Optimise the function to find frequent itemsets of size k given candidate itemsets

Tags: python, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I have written a function to find frequency of itemsets of size k given candidate itemsets. Dataset contains more than 16000 transactions. Can someone please help me in optimizing this function as with current form it is taking about 45 minutes to execute with minSupport=1.

Sample dataset

[image: Dataset]

Comment: Could you share the result of `print(dataSet.head(1))`?

Comment: @abysslover Added in the update. Kindly have a look.

Comment: One _small_ optimization: You're using the `all` function and call it with a list that you built via list comprehension. But you don't need to build a list. A generator expression will work as well and won't be wasting time and memory actually creating the list.

Comment: To achieve this, you just need to remove the square brackets from the line where you use `all`.

Comment: You told you have 16000 transactions, that are processed within 45 minutes. Can you also please tell how many elements are there inside `Ck` that you use in this 45 minutes run? Also each element of Ck is a tuple, can you tell what is average length of this tuple in your 45 minutes run? Also how many columns there are in transactions, i.e. what is value of `transactions.values.shape[1]`?

Comment: @Lagerbaer Thanks, I made this change. Would be of much help if it can be optimised further.

Comment: @Arty I will use this function in Apriori algorithm. It will run with elements in Ck having length of 1, 2, 3, ... till maximum possible that can be achieved with the given minSupport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Algorithm 0** (See other algorithms below)

Implemented boost of your algorithm using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/). Numba is a [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) compiler that converts Python code to very highly optimized C++ code and then compiles to machine code. For many algorithms Numba achieves speed boost of 50-200x times.

To use numba you have to install it through `pip install numba`, notice that Numba is only supported for Python <= 3.8, for 3.9 it is not yet released!

I have rewritten your code a bit to satisfy Numba compilation requirements, my code should be identical by behaviour to yours, please do some tests.

My numba optimized code should give you very good speedup!

I created some artificial short example input data too, to make tests.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66372273#main.py)

```
import numba, numpy as np, pandas as pd

@numba.njit(cache = True)
def selectLkNm(dataSet,Ck,minSupport):
    dict_data = {}
    transactions = dataSet.shape[0]
    for items in Ck:
        count = 0
        while count < transactions:
            if items not in dict_data:
                dict_data[items] = 0
            for item in items:
                for e in dataSet[count, :]:
                    if item == e:
                        break
                else:
                    break
            else:
                dict_data[items] += 1
            count += 1
    Lk = {}
    for k, v in dict_data.items():
        if v >= minSupport:
            Lk[k] = v
    return Lk
    
def selectLk(dataSet, Ck, minSupport):
    tCk = numba.typed.List()
    for e in Ck:
        tCk.append(e)
    return selectLkNm(dataSet.values, tCk, minSupport)

dataset = pd.DataFrame([[100,160,100,160],[170,180,190,200],[100,160,190,200]])
C1 = set()
C1.add((100, 160))
C1.add((170, 180))
C1.add((190, 200))
Lk = selectLk(dataset, C1, 2)
print(Lk)
```

Output:

```
{(100, 160): 2, (190, 200): 2}
```

---

**Algorithm 1** (See other algorithms below)

I improved Algorithm 0 (above) by sorting your data, it will give a good speedup if you have many values inside your Ck or each tuple inside Ck is quite long.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66372273var2#main.py)

```
import numba, numpy as np, pandas as pd

@numba.njit(cache = True)
def selectLkNm(dataSet,Ck,minSupport):
    assert dataSet.ndim == 2
    dataSet2 = np.empty_like(dataSet)
    for i in range(dataSet.shape[0]):
        dataSet2[i] = np.sort(dataSet[i])
    dataSet = dataSet2
    dict_data = {}
    transactions = dataSet.shape[0]
    for items in Ck:
        count = 0
        while count < transactions:
            if items not in dict_data:
                dict_data[items] = 0
            for item in items:
                ix = np.searchsorted(dataSet[count, :], item)
                if not (ix < dataSet.shape[1] and dataSet[count, ix] == item):
                    break
            else:
                dict_data[items] += 1
            count += 1
    Lk = {}
    for k, v in dict_data.items():
        if v >= minSupport:
            Lk[k] = v
    return Lk
    
def selectLk(dataSet, Ck, minSupport):
    tCk = numba.typed.List()
    for e in Ck:
        tCk.append(e)
    return selectLkNm(dataSet.values, tCk, minSupport)

dataset = pd.DataFrame([[100,160,100,160],[170,180,190,200],[100,160,190,200]])
C1 = set()
C1.add((100, 160))
C1.add((170, 180))
C1.add((190, 200))
Lk = selectLk(dataset, C1, 2)
print(Lk)
```

Output:

```
{(100, 160): 2, (190, 200): 2}
```

---

**Algorithm 2** (See other algorithms below)

If you're not allowed to use Numba, then I suggest you next improvements to your algorithm. I pre-sort your dataset to make search of each item not in `O(N)` time but in `O(Log(N))` time which is much much faster.

I see in your code you used pandas dataframe, it means you have installed pandas, and if you installed pandas then you definitely have Numpy, so I decided to use it. You can't have no Numpy if you're dealing with pandas dataframe.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66372273var3#main.py)

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, collections

def selectLk(dataSet,Ck,minSupport):
    dataSet = np.sort(dataSet.values, axis = 1)
    dict_data = collections.defaultdict(int)
    transactions = dataSet.shape[0]
    for items in Ck:
        count = 0
        while count < transactions:
            for item in items:
                ix = np.searchsorted(dataSet[count, :], item)
                if not (ix < dataSet.shape[1] and dataSet[count, ix] == item):
                    break
            else:
                dict_data[items] += 1
            count += 1
    Lk = {k : v for k, v in dict_data.items() if v >= minSupport}
    return Lk
    
dataset = pd.DataFrame([[100,160,100,160],[170,180,190,200],[100,160,190,200]])
C1 = set()
C1.add((100, 160))
C1.add((170, 180))
C1.add((190, 200))
Lk = selectLk(dataset, C1, 2)
print(Lk)
```

Output:

```
{(100, 160): 2, (190, 200): 2}
```

---

**Algorithm 3**

I just had an idea that sorting part of Algorithm 2 may be not the bottleneck, probably transactions while loop can be a bottleneck.

So to improve situation I decided to implement and use a faster algorithm with 2D searchsorted version (there is no built-in 2D version, so it had to be implemented separately), which doesn't have any long pure-python loops, most time is spent in Numpy functions.

Please try if this Algo 3 will be faster, it should be only faster if not sorting was a bottleneck but inner while loop.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66372273var4#main.py)

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, collections

def selectLk(dataSet, Ck, minSupport):
    def searchsorted2d(a, bs):
        s = np.r_[0, (np.maximum(a.max(1) - a.min(1) + 1, bs.ravel().max(0)) + 1).cumsum()[:-1]]
        a_scaled = (a + s[:, None]).ravel()
        def sub(b):
            b_scaled = b + s
            return np.searchsorted(a_scaled, b_scaled) - np.arange(len(s)) * a.shape[1]
        return sub

    assert dataSet.values.ndim == 2, dataSet.values.ndim
    dataSet = np.sort(dataSet.values, axis = 1)
    dict_data = collections.defaultdict(int)
    transactions = dataSet.shape[0]
    Ck = np.array(list(Ck))
    assert Ck.ndim == 2, Ck.ndim
    ss = searchsorted2d(dataSet, Ck)
    for items in Ck:
        cnts = np.zeros((dataSet.shape[0],), dtype = np.int64)
        for item in items:
            bs = item.repeat(dataSet.shape[0])
            ixs = np.minimum(ss(bs), dataSet.shape[1] - 1)
            cnts[...] += (dataSet[(np.arange(dataSet.shape[0]), ixs)] == bs).astype(np.uint8)
        dict_data[tuple(items)] += int((cnts == len(items)).sum())
    return {k : v for k, v in dict_data.items() if v >= minSupport}
    
dataset = pd.DataFrame([[100,160,100,160],[170,180,190,200],[100,160,190,200]])
C1 = set()
C1.add((100, 160))
C1.add((170, 180))
C1.add((190, 200))
Lk = selectLk(dataset, C1, 2)
print(Lk)
```

Output:

```
{(100, 160): 2, (190, 200): 2}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately, I can't use Numba or other external libraries apart from dict I used. It would be of great help if you can alter the existing function with these limits.

Comment: @Ashar As you're using pandas dataframe, can I then use Numpy too? It goes alway where pandas is, so there should be definitely installed numpy where you pandas dataframe and according to your code you have pandas for sure!

Comment: Yeah Numpy is allowed too.

Comment: Algorithm 2 did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Ashar See **Algorithm 2** in my answer, just updated. It uses no Numba, just Numpy. I sort your data before using it. It will greatly improve search speed. Because sorted array can be searched in `O(Log(N))` time instead of `O(N)` which is much much much faster.

Comment: @Ashar Can you also share what is the running speed of my **Algorithm 2** on your full 16000 data?

Comment: Your Algortithm 2 took almost 12 minutes with minimum support 1.

Comment: @Ashar Although it took quite long time (12 minutes) it is mainly because of sorting algorithm, it takes most of time. But later if large sets `Ck` are used then it will still same running time. So algorithm doesn't depend on size of `Ck`, only on size of `dataSet`, because it sorts whole dataset. Also if you run algorithm several times you can reuse same sorted dataset then algorithm will be blazingly fast.

Comment: Yeah I got that. Sorting is the bottleneck here. But still 12 minutes is very much acceptable in my case!

Comment: @Ashar Don't forget to reuse sorted dataset if you're about to run this algorithm several times within one script. Then second run will be blazingly fast because it needs no sorting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229212/discussion-between-arty-and-ashar).

Comment: @Ashar I decided to implement Algo-3 in my answer. Please try it. I had an idea that might be not sorting is a bottleneck, but an inner while loop, so I replaced it with a bit complex but pure-Numpy version. Please come [to this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229212/discussion-between-arty-and-ashar) to discuss some details.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the order of execution of your code. However, since I do not have access to your actual input data, it is difficult to check if the optimized code produces expected outputs and how much speed up you gained.

#### Algorithm 0

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

def selectLk(dataSet,Ck,minSupport):
    dict_data = defaultdict(int)
    for _, row in dataSet.iterrows():
        for items in Ck:
            dict_data[items] += all(item in row.values for item in items)
    Lk = { k : v for k,v in dict_data.items() if v > minSupport}
    return Lk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = list(range(0, 1000, 10))
    df_data = {}
    for i in range(26):
        sample = np.random.choice(data, size=16000, replace=True)
        df_data[f"d{i}"] = sample
    dataset = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
    C1 = set()
    C1.add((100, 160))
    C1.add((170, 180))
    C1.add((190, 200))
    Lk1 = selectLk(dataset, C1, 1)
    dataset = pd.DataFrame([[100,160,100,160],[170,180,190,200],[100,160,190,200]])
    Lk2 = selectLk(dataset, C1, 1)
    print(Lk1)
    print(Lk2)
```

### Algorithm 1

Algorithm 1 utilizes `numpy.equal.outer`, which creates a boolean mask of any matching elements in the Ck tuples. Then, apply `.all()` operation.

```
def selectLk(dataSet, Ck, minSupport):
    dict_data = defaultdict(int)
    dataSet_np = dataSet.to_numpy(copy=False)
    for items in Ck:
        dict_data[items] = dataSet[np.equal.outer(dataSet_np, items).any(axis=1).all(axis=1)].shape[0]
    Lk = { k : v for k, v in dict_data.items() if v > minSupport}
    return Lk
```

Result:

```
{(190, 200): 811, (170, 180): 797, (100, 160): 798}
{(190, 200): 2, (100, 160): 2}
```

Comment: Thanks. My execution time dramatically improved from 45 minutes to 10 minutes!

Comment: @Ashar You will get more performance if you use the algorithm 1. I got around 100x-speed up with my environment.

Comment: Algorithm - 1 is blazing fast. Took me less than a minute!!!

Comment: @Ashar I would appreciate if if you could accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Yours and @Arty both algorithms solved my problem. So sorry, unfortunately I'm unable to mark both as Solved so I upvoted yours.